# Benefitting the deceased by giving charity on his behalf

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices, fatwa

My friend father died – may Allah have mercy on him – and he want to give ongoing charity on behalf of his soul so as to increase his good deeds and raise him in status before his Lord, such as building a mosque or printing a book by which the Muslims will benefit. But one of the person gave us a fatwa stating that this will not benefit him because it is not from his wealth, and ongoing charity has to be set up by the person himself during his own lifetime before his death, and has to continue after his death. Is what the person said correct?
If it is not correct, then please advise me and tell me the best way to benefit to his deceased father.